# How to make a textview show after the button click how to hide the textview again by clicking on the same button in android java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to make a textview show after the button click how to hide the textview again by clicking on the same button in android java.Should i have to try if.else structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FLAG` of some sort to make this happen

```
int i = 0;
            yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(i%2==0){
                 textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }
              else{
                 textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                 i++;
            }

     }
```

Comment: Hi thank everyone for your kind replies,  i used the code    public void onLoveButtonClicked(View view)
    {
     TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.haikuTextView);
     
     if(textview.getVisibility()== View.GONE)
     {
      textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
     else
     {
      textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
     
       
    }                      --it is working fine,but after one show/hidden activity cycle when i click the button again there is no response and only on the second click am getting the hidden/show activity..why is that so???

Answer (score 0):

Initially make the textview disable after clicking the button make it enable,again after clicking the button disable the button.
Use textview.setVisibility() to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In button.setOnClickListner() method put this code:

```
if(textview.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
   textview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}else{
  textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and in layout xml set default visibility of textview as you desire that can be visible or gone or invisible

Answer (score 0):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
           if(textview.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
           {
             textview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
           }
           else
           {
             textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
        }

 }
```